# Как клонировать содержимое балуна?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yandex-maps-api

При геокодировании в балуне на карте получаю адрес объекта. Хочу использовать данные из балуна в дальнейшем, например вывести на веб-страницу полученный адрес, но не знаю как это сделать. Сообразил только как вывести в консоль через команду `console.log(myPlacemark.properties._data.balloonContent)`. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

upd: решил использовать jQuery. Теперь не понимаю как клонировать содержимое балуна.Пробую через `$('#id_164778287350459035376').clone(true).unwrap().appendTo('#ola');`, но ничего не выходит.

Comment: Зачем вы пытаетесь парсить содержимое карты вместо нормального использования данных геокодера  при поиске firstGeoObject.getAddressLine(); ? Посмотрите пример в песочнице, чем он вам не подходит? https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/direct_geocode

Comment: @YaCor', спасибо за ответ. Действительно проще использовать firstGeoObject.getAddressLine(), но просто у меня нет понимания как полученный адрес потом достать на странице приложения. Подскажите тогда как мне, например, добиться alert('У вас цвет - ' +firstGeoObject.getAddressLine()); - т.е. при нажатии на карту, всплывало бы окно с выбранным адресом.

Comment: А в чём проблема вставить эту строку кода в скрипт карты? Насколько вижу, код корректно обрабатывается и высвечивает алерт: https://ibb.co/pWL48rc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения было достаточно вывести переменную, содержащую координаты, в начало скрипта, тем самым сделав переменную глобальной.